# how to copy files from windows to linux using winscp in batchfile

Tags: linux, windows, file, batch-file, copy

I tried like this
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://user@host -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
synchronize remote C:\Users\Desktop\ /data.

I am getting the error as below mention
syncronize is not recognized as an internal or external command,operational program or batch file. It would be grateful if anyone suggest.Thanks in adv.

Comment: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline?